# List of numbers to 2d int array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I have a list of numbers on a textbox like so (the numbers used are just examples):

1 1 1

2 2 2

...

So I want to convert that into a 2d array. I know to use .ToArray() or Regex.Split() for 1d lists but am not sure how to use that for 2d. I've also tried to use those functions on a string[] array to make it 2d but there was an error.

Also, the array is supposed to be an int[,] so that the values in the array can be compared. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `the array is supposed to be an int[,]` is this homework?

Comment: No, this is for myself, to use as a code generator for yet another program. It's supposed to be int since I have to compare parts of the array with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, if you don't understand any part please ask in the comments:

```
        // assuming the numbers are in perfect 2D format in textBox (only 1 newline separates the lines, only 1 space separates numbers in each line and all lines have the same amount of numbers)
        string textWithNumbers = textBox.Text;

        // first put all lines into an string array
        string[] allLines = textWithNumbers.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // calculate 2D array's dimension lengths, and initialize the 2Darray
        int rowCount = allLines.Length;
        int columnCount = ((allLines[0].Length + 1) / 2);
        int[,] twoDArray = new int[rowCount, columnCount];

        // we then iterate through the 2D array
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            // parse each number from string format to integer format & assign it to the corresponding location in our 2D array
            string[] line = allLines[row].Split(' ');
            for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
            {
                twoDArray[row, column] = int.Parse(line[column]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: array[row, column] = int.Parse(line[column]); gives an error: input string not in correct format.

Comment: @SharkRetriever: that means just what the exception is telling you: one of your numbers in your set is not in correct format and the run-time could not convert it from its string representation to its integer representation. See line[column]'s value when the program breaks to find the problematic number with incorrect format, or post your set of numbers on http://pastebin.com so I can check.

Comment: I have changed the array to a string one, and I got another error saying out of range index. Truth is, I'm confused by how you obtained columncount's amount. I am also confused by how the split works, since I'm used to simpler things like 
string[] a3 = Regex.Split(a2, "  ");

Comment: @SharkRetriever, since in your example there is 1 space between each number in each line, the number of columns(number of numbers in each line) will always be the floor of `((number of spaces) + (number of numbers) + 1) / 2` . The +1 is for lines that have an odd length. I used this formula to avoid an additional split; you can easily replace the line with `int columnCount = allLines[0].Split(' ').Length;`

Comment: `Split` just takes an string and splits it into an array depending on the delimiter(s) you provide. Since your number delimiter in each line is an space, we have used `Split(' ')` to split the first line with the space as delimiter and put the numbers in an string array.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a nice jagged 2D array that doesn't depend on all the text boxes having the same length. If you need them to all be the same length, it's trivial to check.

```
string[] data = // text input from all the text boxes

var result = data.Select(x => x.Split(' ')
    .Select(y => int.Parse(y)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Result is not quite an int[,] but an int[int[]], which is practically the same thing.

Of course, you need to deal with input validation or error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first start with the most naive solution, this makes very few assumptions about the data entered by the user. For example, it does not assume that every row has the same number of entries etc. So this could be optimized for those special conditions that you might know hold true or can enforce before running this routine.

```
  // This is the data from the textbox 
  // hardcoded here for demonstration
  string data = "1 1 1" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "2 2 2" + Environment.NewLine 
    + "12 12 12";

  // First we need to determine the size of array dimension
  // How many rows and columns do we need
  int columnCount;
  int rowCount;

  // We get the rows by splitting on the new lines
  string[] rows = data.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  rowCount = rows.Length;

  // We iterate through each row to find the max number of items
  columnCount = 0;
  foreach (string row in rows)
  {
    int length = row.Split(' ').Length;
    if (length > columnCount) columnCount = length;
  }

  // Allocate our 2D array
  int[,] myArray = new int[rowCount, columnCount];

  // Populate the array with the data
  for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
  {
    // Get each row of data and split the string into the
    // separate components
    string[] rowData = rows[i].Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < rowData.length; ++j)
    {
      // Convert each component to an integer value and 
      // enter it into the 2D array
      int value;
      if (int.TryParse(rowData[j], out value))
      {
        myArray[i, j] = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Given the above where we are considering the possibility of each row not having the same number of elements, you might consider using a sparse array `int[][]` which coincidentally also yield better performance in .NET.